# Is there a way to change default cursor styles in VTKJS?

Tags: javascript, css, opengl, vtk, vtk.js

I am working on a project where I have created different kinds of tools (Ex: Pan, Zoom, Rotate) using VTKJS. Each time I select any of this tools particular functionality activates (Ex: When I select Zoom then I am able to zoom in and zoom out the image).Now the issue is if I select any of these tools the default style for cursor applied which is `cursor: pointer` and I want to change different cursor styles for each tool item. Is there any way in VTKJS that I can change this default behavior.
Ex: For Zoom I need zoom-in, For Pan I need pointer, For Rotate its default(arrow).

Now what I have tried is on each of this tool items I have created  event listeners

```
 zoomButton.setAttribute("style", "cursor:zoom-in !important");
```

and it works fine and it changes the cursor icons. But whenever I try to zoom-in or zoom-out the cursor revert back to `cursor:pointer`. So is their ant way we can handle this ?

Comment: apply style on canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the cursor via an interactor or renderWindow object via the `setCursor()` method. For example:

```js
import vtkGenericRenderWindow from 'vtk.js/Sources/Rendering/Misc/GenericRenderWindow';

const genericRenderWindow = vtkGenericRenderWindow.newInstance();
const renderWindow = genericRenderWindow.getRenderWindow();

renderWindow.setCursor('zoom-in');
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the `behaviour.js` file of a widget you can add `model.interactor.getView().setCursor('wait');` this changes the cursor to your preference.

```
publicAPI.handleButtonRelease = (e) => {
    model.interactor.getView().setCursor('wait');
}
```